# When creating directory with Ansible it doesnt appear

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have this simple ansible flow: I want to create a directory on the host:

```
- name: Create rails app dir
  file: path=/etc/rails-app state=directory mode=0755
  register: rails_app_dir
```

And these are the logs when I run the playbook:

```
TASK [instance_deploy_app : Create rails app dir] *************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/instance_deploy_app/tasks/main.yml:39
<IPv4 of host> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<IPv4 of host> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<IPv4 of host> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/files/file.py
<IPv4 of host> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-25617Cg_rWo/tmpTPHs3p TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297/AnsiballZ_file.py
<IPv4 of host> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297/AnsiballZ_file.py && sleep 0'
<IPv4 of host> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297/AnsiballZ_file.py && sleep 0'
<IPv4 of host> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1645566978.53-25820-207749605236297/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [IPv4 of host] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "diff": {
        "after": {
            "path": "/etc/rails-app"
        }, 
        "before": {
            "path": "/etc/rails-app"
        }
    }, 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_diff_peek": null, 
            "_original_basename": null, 
            "access_time": null, 
            "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S", 
            "attributes": null, 
            "backup": null, 
            "content": null, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": true, 
            "force": false, 
            "group": null, 
            "mode": "0755", 
            "modification_time": null, 
            "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S", 
            "owner": null, 
            "path": "/etc/rails-app", 
            "recurse": false, 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": null, 
            "state": "directory", 
            "unsafe_writes": null
        }
    }, 
    "mode": "0755", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "path": "/etc/rails-app", 
    "size": 41, 
    "state": "directory", 
    "uid": 0
}
Read vars_file 'roles/instance_deploy_app/vars/instance_vars.yml'
Read vars_file 'roles/instance_deploy_app/vars/aws_cred.yml'
```

According to the logs, the directory should be there but when I try to access `/etc/rails-app/` it is not there. I currently have 3 users in the AWS EC2 instance: ec2-user, root and user1 and I tried to check in all of them but the directory doesnt appear.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "_I want to check if a directory exists on the host and if not, create it_" ... Since Ansible is a configuration management tool with which you declare a state, there is no need to check before. You need only one task which creates a directory, it will be idempotent.

Comment: Still the problem is that even when I create it, it is still not there... @U880D

Comment: Can you change your workflow to the directory creation task only, register the result and provide the output from that, all within in your original question (edited)?

Comment: Sure, done! Please let me know what you think @U880D

Comment: you do have somewhere (probably in your inventory) a line like ansible_connection: local` which means you never connects to your EC2 and always acts on your controller. This is pointed by _<IPv4 of host> ESTABLISH **LOCAL CONNECTION** FOR USER: root_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was not creating the folder, as β.εηοιτ.βε suggested, is because in the playbook I had `connection: local` so it was "never connecting to my EC2 and always acting on my controller". Once I removed that, it worked.